# There's any way to run two JVM in the same server?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm having some issues with the JVM; I have a Web page and an application with no GUI(UDP server), and both uses the same database, the application(UDP server) it's working ok but if the web application get out of memory the whole JVM stop; so I was thinking to put the UDP server in a different JVM.

I'm getting the following messages

> *May 21, 2013 5:24:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>
>   SEVERE: The web application [/track] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.opengts.util.ThreadLocalMap$1] (value [org.opengts.util.ThreadLocalMap$1@277085a4]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gts?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&characterSetResults=utf8=org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection@22236dae}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.*

and when I restart the web page

```
May 21, 2013 5:24:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2695 ms
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1336)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:176)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.processSocket(JIoEndpoint.java:510)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:229)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-8" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:657)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:943)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:992)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

## NEW INFO

I tried the ulimit command getting the following results.

```
ulimit
unlimited
ulimit -Hn
163840
ulimit -n
163840
ulimit -u
1024
```

Now I'm wondering what's the meaning of those numbers?
They are the amount of process or memory in MBytes?

Comment: You absolutely can run multiple JVMs on one physical machine.  People do it all the time.  Just make sure the apps don't share ports that they want to bind too.

Comment: Do you have some link to a tutorial related to this?, cause I never do something like that.

Comment: I am running at least fifteen JVMs in my server. Twelve Tomcats for the webapp, another Tomcat for VMWare, another for JVisualVM, another for JXplorer, ...

Comment: It sounds to me as if you may be running the machine out of available task handles.  They're supposed to be recycled, but I've seen cases on my Mac where they run out.  A Java app that creates a lot of threads and doesn't neatly end them would make matters worse.

Comment: Any tutorial related to how to start multiple JVM's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread" error isn't really an out of memory error at all -- the JVM is unable to create a new thread due to an OS limitation.

What OS are you using? On linux, you can increase this by doing:

```
ulimit -u <new limit>
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to run web servers on different ports
so it's not JVM  issue - it's configuration of catalina

Comment: Funny, I was going to mention that this makes a excellent comment, when I reclaimed, it made an reasonable answer...;)

Comment: Let me understand, if I'm not misunderstand those errors are because a wrong catalina configuration?

Comment: Are you talking about "http-bio-8080-exec-8" and "http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0"(both in port 8080)? Because I don't understand what is wrong and what are you referring to with "web servers" I just have one web page.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating new JVM I would examine Thread creation first.

I had the same problem with number of Threads limitation until I added

```
executor.shutdown();
```

for ExecutorService within the finally block

Comment: In what file do you add that line of code? java.lang? ThreadPolExecutor.java?

Comment: @E_Blue Are you using an executor service in your app?

Comment: I guess, cause one of the error lines say org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:156)
I didn't create the web app I just edit some minor java archives.